# Export content to CSV file

Tags: laravel

I am using `"league/csv": "^8.2"`package for CSV export/import and I try this code to export content to CSV file:

```
public function exportCSV($id)
{
    $users= User::find($id);

    $csv = \League\Csv\Writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject());
    $csv->insertOne(\Schema::getColumnListing('users'));
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $csv->insertOne($user->toArray());
    }
    $csv->output('users.csv');
}
```

But I'm getting error `FatalErrorException: Call to a member function toArray() on boolean`.

When I do `dd($users)` I get the Collection, not the boolean value. Any help?

**EDIT**

@Alexey Mezenin's answer helped me. But is there a way to insert new column using this package? I've tried this:

```
$rows     = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
        'test',
    ];
$csv = \League\Csv\Writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject());
$csv->insertAll($rows);
$csv->output('users.csv');
```

But it inserts data into new row every time. Like:

```
'1,2,3
foo, bar,baz
test
```

I want to have a new column for each array...

**EDIT 2**

I solved it using:

```
$csv->setDelimiter(';');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `find()` you're getting an instance of a `User` model, not a collection. Use get instead:

```
$users = User::get();
```

If you want to get just one use by ID, remove the loop:

```
$user = User::find($id);
....
$csv->insertOne($user->toArray());
```

Comment: Thx. It helped, but still I don't have what I need... Btw. I've edited my question!